# Non-nagativity of directional derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

For $U$ open and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $u\in C^1(\overline{U})$, the directional derivative,
\begin{equation}
   \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x_0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{u(x_0)-u(x_0-h\nu)}{h}
\end{equation}
**Statment:**
If $u(x_0)>u(x)$ for all $x\in U$, then we get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x_0)\geq0$

**Question:**
The positivity is clear but the equality id bit unclear to me. It seems that as $h\rightarrow0$ the term $u(x_0-h\nu)$ should approach $u(x_0)$ faster than $h$ approaches 0. Is this the case or am I complete wrong?

Comment: And $\nu$ is outward unit normal to the boundary of $U$ at $x_0$

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of the directional derivative is unusual. Let me redefine the directional derivative, for all unit vector $\nu\in\mathbb R^n$ and $x_0\in U$ by:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(x_0+h\nu) - u(x_0)}{h}.$$
Then if $u(x_0)>u(x)$ for all $x\in U$ with $x\neq x_0$, it means you have a global maximum over $U$. Therefore, $u$ strictly decreases whenever you "move sligthly away" from $x_0$, no matter the direction (since the maximum is **global** and **unique**). In other words:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}(x_0) < 0, \qquad \forall \nu\in\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}.$$
You can simply prove this by contradiction, assuming that there exists $\nu_0\neq0$ such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu_0}(x_0)\geq 0$. It should contradicts that $u(x_0)>u(x)$ for $x\neq x_0$.

Comment: Thanks, but the definitions for D.D. are equivalent I think. But the point is the global maximum, of course, Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: They are equivalent up to a minus sign. I just used what is probably more "standard" to avoid mistakes.